# can i only use 2 speakers on a 5.1 system I am looking to connect only two speakers 

Tags: 5.1

can i only use 2 speakers on a 5.1 system I am looking to connect only two speakers so I can have music outside only

Comment: you mean downmix 5.1 to stereo?

Answer (score 1):

If the 5.1 is running from a shared amplifier you will need a dummy-load so as not to damage the amp.

http://diyaudioprojects.com/Technical/DIY-Speaker-Dummy-Load/

Answer (score 1):

@Bill Your question is quite unclear to me... You mean, you want the audio from your 5.1 system to only be reproduced in 2 speakers? You want to reproduce the audio that is divided through the 6 channels and send it only to 2 of them? or do you wish only to mute the other 4 channels?